# Textbox not diplaying text as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to coding. I cannot figure out why my text box will not display text in windows forms using C#. Here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        Form1 myTestObject = new Form1();
        myTestObject.myTextPanel("hello");
    }

    public void myTextPanel(string myText)
    {
        // Windows Forms textBox1
        textBox1.Text = myText;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted an answer below, Could you please take a look, let me know if you need any more details or explanation..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running an instance of the `Form1` and then create a new instance of the same( keep in mind both are different instance) and assigning values. you can Try this:

```
Form1 myTestObject = new Form1();
myTestObject.myTextPanel("hello");
Application.Run(myTestObject);
```

which will use the same instance of the `Form1`so you can see the text is appearing; you can make use of the constructor as well, instead for the `myTextPanel` method, the constructor will looks like the following:

```
public void Form1(string myText)
{
    // Windows Forms textBox1
    textBox1.Text = myText;
    // Do something
}
```

if so the main will changed as like the following:

```
Form1 myTestObject = new Form1("hello");  
Application.Run(myTestObject);
```

or like this :

```
Application.Run(new Form1("hello"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question of why the text was not displaying and offering additional help. When you add the Application.Run in your first code snippit it creates another Form1. So it will display Form1 blank with no text then it will display another Form1 with the text. I would like to use only one Form1 that will use the myTestObject.myTextPanel("hello"); line of code unmodified and be able to use another line myTestObject.myTextPanel("GoodBye"); to update the output of the textBox1.